# How to remove app license information of apps downloaded from Microsoft store?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

We have created an app in Microsoft store. When we download an app, we get a license "Full License". Uninstalling an app, does not remove license. **so my question is where is these license info stored and how to remove it.**

Why i am asking this question? :  I am doing experiment with Windows.Services.Store and learning how to access addon information etc. I wish to try experimenting setting app to trial version and then asking user to buy an app.  But since I had set app free, the download and install has acquired full license.

I am using Microsoft UWP Sample (Store C# Sample) to experiment. You already brought this app and have a "full license" version.

I then created a new submission and set app price and also set trail period. but MSFT sample application say the same error "You already brought this app and have a full license version."

**So i repeat my question: where is these license info stored and how to remove it.**

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where is these license info stored and how to remove it.

Currently, the license information is managed by the Store and you can't manually check and manipulate the license.

Once you've purchased an app on your app, then it will have a full license on your device and other users will be able to access it as well. The suggestion for testing is that you could create a test app on the Partner Center and associate that new app with your project. Then use the new app to test the trial function.